# Cannot open .accdb files because Access looking for hard-coded path

Tags: ms-access

I have received a few `.accdb` files from a client, and I am trying to open them in `Microsoft Access 2013`.  The files seem to open correctly, but whenever I click on any of the tables or queries on the left I get the following error message:

```
C:\[hard-coded path on client's computer] is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.
```

Now, I know that the path does not exist on my computer.  But why is Access looking for a hard-coded path on another person's computer?  And how can I access the tables and queries in Access?

Additional question: Is there an easy way to import the data to `SQL Server` instead?  I read a couple of posts about importing data from `Access` to `SQL Server`, but apparently the `SQL Server Import and Export Wizard` is expecting a file of a different format, not `.accdb`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is likely the tables are linked to one or more external data sources, hence the path error.  You may have received only the front-end accdb's containing forms, etc., but no data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the back-end database file from your client. All the tables are stored there. Once you receive it, save it at a convenient location on your computer and use the "Linked Table Manager" on the "External Data" tab in the .accdb you already have. That will allow you to update the table links for the current location of the back-end database file on your system.

Comment: Can you please tell me what would be the extension of that backend database file

Comment: It should be the same as your frontend. Either  MDB in Access 2000 or 2002-2003 formats or an ACCDB.